# Executable created with cx_freeze not working

Tags: python, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I have a python GUI program created with PyQt5 which I am trying to freeze into a windows executable using cx_freeze. The build works fine but the program returns a host of errors when I try to run the executable.

Below is my setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [])

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('mainbeam.py', base=base)
]

setup(
    name='BeamFEA',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'A program for solving beam problems using FEM',
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
    executables = executables
)
```

A snapshot of the returned errors:

[image]

Comment: You might want to try [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) instead, I often had better results with that.

Comment: Pyinstaller got same bugs(if not install pyinstaller developer, ofcourse need LSB,MSB and objective-C).